# delegate for a singleton object

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a NSObject which is a singleton. Is there any issue of having a delegate for this singleton class? I am worried that it would fail for a singleton type.

Here's my scenario. I have a function (inside this singleton class) that does a async request to pull out a NSDictionary from an API. Basically when this request is done I want to notify a class that the request has finished.

Comment: Why would a delegate fail? You may consider using `NSNotificationCenter` instead, for multiple listeners.

Comment: I only have one class that I want to notify, updated the question context as well above

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, a delegate wouldn't fail, but consider using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead:

```
static NSString *const kMyClassNotificationName = @"myClassNotificationName";

// where you would call a delegate method (e.g. [self.delegate doSomething])
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMyClassNotificationName object:self userInfo: /* dictionary containing variables to pass to the delegate */];

// where you would set up a delegate (e.g. [Singleton instance].delegate = self)
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething) name:kMyClassNotificationName object:[Singleton instance]];
```

Comment: @adit If you desperately need to speed up observer lookup, you can use a special instance of `NSNotificationCenter` in your singleton. In that case just make it a read only property of your singleton so that observers can register with it directly.

Comment: This really is bad form. Why would anyone purposely mince the code like this? See vikingosegundo's answer for 2 better solutions with a delegate or blocks

Comment: @PostCodeism I'm not sure I follow. What is wrong with my code? How would YOU use NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII sorry, that was an overreaction. Nothing wrong with your code specifically, I was more so talking about NSNotifications in general. It's just that NSNotifications are overused because they're easy, but they're extremely hard to trace through code. Overall, Blocks would be the better solution for singletons in iOS.

Comment: @PostCodeism no, not for a multicast solution. They are both tools for different scenarios, obviously there is no catch-all solution.

Answer (score 19):

You have basically three options:

- Use a delegate. A singelton is a objetct, so of couse it can have a delegate. If several objects whants to use it and needs to set themselves as delegates, you can reset them each time, but that might get hairy.
- Use notifications, as shown by Richard J. Ross III., but seriously: It seems to be strange to me, if you have a singleton, that needs to inform one delegate, but you'd use a broadcasting technology.
- use completion blocks, where the calling objects passes a block to the singleton, that gets executed, once the singleton fulfilled a task. See [`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_1) (ok, this is not a singleton, but a class method. The principle is the same),that uses one completion block, or the great [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/), that uses a success and a failure block.
  From it's example codes:

  ```
  [[AFGowallaAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:urlString 
                                  parameters:mutableParameters 
                                     success:^(__unused AFHTTPRequestOperation 
                                               *operation, 
                                               id JSON) 
      {
          NSMutableArray *mutableRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
          for (NSDictionary *attributes in [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"spots"]) {
              Spot *spot = [[[Spot alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes] autorelease];
              [mutableRecords addObject:spot];
          }

          if (block) {
              block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableRecords]);
          }
      } failure:^(__unused AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          if (block) {
              block([NSArray array]);
          }
  }];
  ```

Comment: Dear reviewers: Editing a post to fix typos is ok and appreciated. But adding links to libraries I don't even know is not.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with having a delegate for a singleton, but it does create a lot of edge cases that you need to handle. Such as:

- If object A calls setDelegate:, followed immediately by object B calling setDelegate: then object A will never receive delegate calls.
- You need to check whether you are the delegate before unsetting the singleton's delegate. Typically in `dealloc` you call `singleton.delegate = nil;`. If another object happened to become delegate after you did, then you just caused caused them to unexpectedly stop being delegate.

Singletons with delegates is not a well-established pattern. Your solutions should vary depending on how robust your use case is.  Here are some solutions (in order of easiest -> most robust).

**Keep it simple**

Design your App to never have multiple objects being the singleton's delegate at the same time (this may be impossible).

**NSNotification**

Use NSNotificationCenter to signal events instead of delegation. See some of the other answers posted in this thread.

**Multiple Delegates**

Extend your singleton to support multiple delegate. Replace `setDelegate:` with: `addDelegate:` and `removeDelegate:`

```
@property (atomic) NSMutableArray *delegates;

- (void)addDelegate:(NSObject * <YourProtocol>)foo {
    [self.delegates addObject:foo];
}
- (void)removeDelegate:(NSObject * <YourProtocol>)foo {
    [self.delegates removeObject:foo];
}
- (void)signalDelegateEvent {
    [self.delegates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id<YourProtocol> obj,
                                                 NSUInteger idx,
                                                 BOOL *stop) {
        // call delegate method `foo` on each delegate
        if ( [obj respondsToSelector:@selector(foo)]) {
            [obj foo];
        } 
    }];
}
```

I have used the multi-delegate pattern successfully in many apps. Be careful to think about how multi-threading effects things if you choose this approach.

Comment: I never thought of using a multi delegate solution, thanks for the idea. Good to have a variation of the delegate pattern in mind

Comment: How about having a required callback to notify delegate objects that they are about to be replaced?

Comment: This solution could use an NSSet instead of NSArray to collect the delegates to ensure nothing receives multiple messages.